# Visualise networkx graph in Gephi

Tags: python, networkx, gephi

I want to visualise my **networkx** graph in **Gephi**. My graph has two types of nodes `ntype="main"` and `ntype="sub"` as follows.

```
    [('organisation', {'ws': 347.9, 'ntype': 'main'}), ('employee', {'ws': 0, 'ntype': 'sub'}), 
('minor_staff', {'ws': 0, 'ntype': 'sub'}), ('assets', {'ws': 0, 'ntype': 'sub'}), 
('stocks', {'ws': 315.0, 'ntype': 'main'}), ('HR', {'ws': 0, 'ntype': 'sub'}), 
('Director_board', {'ws': 0, 'ntype': 'sub'}), ('stakeholders', {'ws': 0.1, 'ntype': 'sub'}),
 ('stockmarket', {'ws': 488.5, 'ntype': 'main'}), ('events', {'ws': 0, 'ntype': 'sub'}),
 ('facilities', {'ws': 0, 'ntype': 'extended'})]
```

When visualising with Gephi, I want to show my `main` nodes as blue and `sub` nodes as grey.

Is there any special way of saving the nodes in networkx, for Gephi to identify these color codes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522155/adding-color-attribute-to-nodes-on-networkx-to-export-to-gephi Try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
import networkx as nx
""" Create a graph with three nodes"""
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('red', ws=1.0, ntype = 'main')
G.add_node('green', ws=1.5, ntype = 'sub')
G.add_node('blue', ws=1.2, ntype = 'sub')

for item in G.nodes(data = True):
    if item[1]['ntype'] == 'main':
        G.node[item[0]]['viz'] = {'color': {'r': 255, 'g': 0, 'b': 0, 'a': 0}}
    elif item[1]['ntype'] == 'sub':
        G.node[item[0]]['viz'] = {'color': {'r': 0, 'g': 255, 'b': 0, 'a': 0}}

""" Write to GEXF """
# Use 1.2draft so you do not get a deprecated warning in Gelphi
nx.write_gexf(G, "file2.gexf", version="1.2draft")
```