# Exporting edge colors to Gephi from NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, gephi

Adding colored nodes is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522155/adding-color-attribute-to-nodes-on-networkx-to-export-to-gephi?noredirect=1&lq=1).

However, a similar method does not work for edges, it seems.

At the moment the edges of my graph are different colors in NetworkX, but Gephi can't seem to see that.

I have tried:

```
edge[2]['viz'] = {color: {'r': 255, 'g': 0, 'b': 0, 'a': 0}}
```

and Gephi just ignores the color property.

Is there a way to add colored edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here was that I had alpha `'a'` set to `0`.

Setting it to *literally any positive number* will solve the issue / save hours of your time.

```
edge[2]['viz'] = {color: {'r': 255, 'g': 0, 'b': 0, 'a': 1.0}}
```